# Using Google Sheets and Google Scripts - How do I insert an entry from a cell into a variable?

Tags: google-sheets

This is my first time playing with a JSON API and my java is super rusty.

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Pull a string from a Google Sheets cell into function getSymbol (name). In this case, the string should be "Ethereum"
2. Insert the name variable into a url string, which is where the JSON I want to pull lives. In this case, the API output looks like this:

   [
       {
           "id": "ethereum", 
           "name": "Ethereum", 
           "symbol": "ETH", 
           "rank": "2", 
           "price_usd": "95.3675", 
           "price_btc": "0.0605977", 
           "24h_volume_usd": "152223000.0", 
           "market_cap_usd": "8713986432.0", 
           "available_supply": "91372705.0", 
           "total_supply": "91372705.0", 
           "percent_change_1h": "0.38", 
           "percent_change_24h": "1.38", 
           "percent_change_7d": "37.07", 
           "last_updated": "1494105266"
       }
   ]
3. Next I want to pull the "symbol" item from the JSON and return that back to the spreadsheet. In this case, the function would take in "Ethereum" and return "ETH".

Below is my code. Whenever I run it I get an error saying my name variable is undefined, resulting in a URL that looks like this (says "undefined" instead of "ethereum"):

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/undefined/?convert=USD

What am I doing wrong?

```
function getSymbol (name) {
var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"+name+"/?convert=USD";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = response.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  var sym = json["symbol"];

  return sym;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is an array of objects i.e. `json = [{object1},{object2}]`
Even though there is just one element, you still need to access it like so

```
var sym = json[0]["symbol"]
//or
var sym = json[0].symbol
```

Your final code will look like this:

```
function getSymbol (name) {
var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"+name+"/?convert=USD";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = response.getContentText();

  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  var sym = json[0]["symbol"];

  return sym;

  }
```